# django CMS render_model_add twice for same model in template

Tags: django, django-cms

```
<h2>News{% render_model_add news.0 %}</h2>
<h2>News{% render_model_add news.0 %}</h2>
```

First line works OK and there is a plus icon near "News" label but second line of code shows only label without plus icon.

Also when use `render_model_block` twice for same instance in single template i can edit only the first one.

Is there any way how to allow add/edit model from multiple places on single page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently this is not supported as we use the object's primary key to compose the id for the object's editing container.

Ticket for reference: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/5677